# How to get most viewed you tube video using javascript API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to get the list of video sorted by most viewed you tube video.I have been trying the following code but it is not returning any response.

```
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
                part: 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                q: query,
                maxResults: count,
                order:'viewCount'
            });
request.execute(onSearchResponse);
```

Above code does not return any response.Can someone please redirect me in right direction I have already looked into documentation.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list

Answer (score 1):

Using the YouTube API v3 *(and modifying the parameters supplied in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472788/4092887))*, you can use this request URL for get the most viewed YouTube video.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&part=snippet&order=viewcount&maxResults=1
```

The following information was taken from the [YouTube Data API - official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en):

- **key**: your API key.
- **part**: The part parameter specifies a comma-separated list of one or more search resource properties that the API response will include. Set the parameter value to *`snippet`*.
- **[order](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?hl=en)**<sup>1</sup>:  in this case, is used *`viewcount`*.
- **maxResults**: specifies the maximum number of items that should be returned in the result set. Acceptable values are 0 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5.

---

<sup>1</sup> Linked documentation says that only these values are allowed in the `order` parameter:

- **date**: Resources are sorted in reverse chronological order based on the date they were created.
- **rating**: Resources are sorted from highest to lowest rating.
- **relevance**: Resources are sorted based on their relevance to the search query. This is the default value for this parameter.
- **title**: Resources are sorted alphabetically by title.
- **videoCount**: Channels are sorted in descending order of their number of uploaded videos.
- **viewCount**: Resources are sorted from highest to lowest number of views. For live broadcasts, videos are sorted by number of concurrent viewers while the broadcasts are ongoing.