# How to get ID of last uploaded video to YouTube?

Tags: youtube

Is it possible to get the ID of the last uploaded video to the specific YouTube channel, based on channel name, eventually channel ID?

I need get a thumbnail from last video:

```
http://img.youtube.com/vi/<VIDEO-ID>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get this video id you can use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/)

You can make a curl request to: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=1

This would return a JSON with a video id for the latest youtube video.